# Heroku: ENOTFOUND error on deploy node app with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am trying to publish my webservice developed in nodeJS using mondoDb as database but I am having the following error and I have not been able to solve it

```
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-qqlqa.mongodb.net
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/callback_resolver:47:19) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'querySrv',
hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-qqlqa.mongodb.net'
}
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.